# Mining not working in Dwarf Fortress v0.43

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Whenever I try to mine, it doesn't work. I press `D` for designate, then `D` again for mine. Then I press `Enter`, and it makes the green cross. But once I press `Enter` in a different place, it just gets rid of the green cross and doesn't make a highlighted box. I've tried using `<`and `>`, but going onto a different level doesn't help either.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, they key combination is <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, not <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. But you already know this, because the first part ("green cross") worked.

It seems that you have accidentally selected "automining" (<kbd>a</kbd>), and the area you are trying to mine doesn't contain useful minerals - if so, press <kbd>a</kbd> a few more times until it chooses "normal mining".